# Fluent API e Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, fluent-api

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

```
public abstract class Pessoa
{

   /* Propriedades do Pessoa*/
   public Guid IdPessoa { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente : Pessoa
{
    public Cliente()
    {
       IdPessoa = Guid.NewGuid();
       Enderecos = new List<Endereco>()
    }
    /* Propriedades do Cliente */
    public virtual string CPF {get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
}

public class Fornecedor : Pessoa
{
    public Fornecedor()
    {
       IdPessoa = Guid.NewGuid();
       Enderecos = new List<Endereco>()
    }

    public virtual string CNPJ {get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
}
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer:

1º - Usar o *migration* para criar a base, mas no meu teste ele gera a tabela `pessoa` com todos os atributos e as classes que estendem `Pessoa` apenas com o `IdPessoa` e a propriedade particular de cada uma. Gostaria de saber se posso usar ou se tenho que mapear na unha?

2º - Na entidade `Endereco` ele vai possuir apenas número, complemento, CEP e o `IdPessoa`. Porem não sei se isso é possível. Se não for eu posso ter na mesma entidade (`endereco`) atributos como `IdCliente`, `IdFornecedor` ... Id .... conforme for precisando e somente preenchendo de acordo com a entidade persistida (na minha visão, tenho quase certeza que isso seria uma gambiarra), qual seria a alternativa: uma tabela pra cada entidade tipo `ClienteEndereco`, `FornecedorEndereco` e se for isso como ficaria minhas classes e o mapeamento?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você poderia adicionar a forma como você está mapeando esses tipos e as propriedades em questão? A forma na qual o EF decide qual a estratégia (TPH, TPC ou TPT) ele vai usar na hora de transformar em tabelas depende exclusivamente de como você mapeia a sua hierarquia nele.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando falamos em mapear classes que utilizam hierarquias para tabelas, independentemente de ORM, temos 3 padrões conhecidos:

**Tabela por Hierarquia (TPH)**

Ocorre a desnormalização total das tabelas, ou seja, a transformação de todos os campos definidos em todas as classes em uma mesma tabela.

Quando isso acontece, todas as propriedades próprias de classes filhas viram campos NULL e o Entity Framework cria um campo "Discriminator" para saber a qual entidade filha aquele registro pertence.

**Tabela por Tipo (TPT)**

O tipo pai e todos os seus filhos ganham uma tabela própria cada, onde a classe abstrata possui a chave primária e cada filho possui como chave primária apenas a chave estrangeira do tipo pai.

Quando isso acontece, temos um cenário plenamente normalizado, pois nenhum campo se repete.

**Tabela por Tipo Concreto (TPC)**

Quando seu objetivo é ter uma tabela separada para cada classe filha, não importando a repetição de campos na classe abstrata, esse é o tipo desejado.

Implementar esse tipo de modelo geralmente dá um trabalho a mais, pois cada entidade deve gerar um Id próprio, ao mesmo tempo em que na modelagem de classes, eles possuem o mesmo campo de identidade na classe abstrata.

> 1º - Usar o migration para criar a base, mas no meu teste ele gera a tabela pessoa com todos os atributos e as classes que estendem Pessoa apenas com o IdPessoa e a propriedade particular de cada uma. Gostaria de saber se posso usar ou se tenho que mapear na unha ?

Pela forma que você descreveu na questão, parece que está ocorrendo o padrão TPT para o Pessoa mas você quer um TPC. No seu caso, como Pessoa não possui campos próprios e o IdPessoa que cada filho carrega é um Guid independente um do outro, o TPC parece ser a melhor solução para a sua abstração.

Considerando as suas classes acima, temos a seguinte configuração para as classes de Pessoa, independentemente do padrão:

```cs
public DbSet<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // mapeamento específico conforme o padrão

    // mapeamento comum das classes
    modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>().HasKey(x => x.IdPessoa);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>().Property(x => x.IdPessoa)
                                 .IsRequired()
                                 .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>().Property(x => x.CPF)
                                  .IsRequired()
                                  .IsFixedLength()
                                  .IsUnicode(false)
                                  .HasColumnType("char")
                                  .HasMaxLength(11);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Fornecedor>().Property(x => x.CNPJ)
                                     .IsRequired()
                                     .IsFixedLength()
                                     .IsUnicode(false)
                                     .HasColumnType("char")
                                     .HasMaxLength(14);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Um exemplo de criação de base e registros para cada tipo de pessoa:

```
Database.SetInitializer<Contexto>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Contexto>());

using (var contexto = new Contexto())
{
    var cliente = new Cliente { CPF = "74182476808" }; // gerado aleatoriamente
    contexto.Pessoas.Add(cliente);

    var fornecedor = new Fornecedor { CNPJ = "89205398000106" }; // gerado aleatoriamente
    contexto.Pessoas.Add(fornecedor);

    contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

Considerando que parece que você possui um caso de TPT, seu mapeamento específico deve possuir algo como:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>().ToTable("Cliente");
modelBuilder.Entity<Fornecedor>().ToTable("Fornecedor");
```

E consequentemente, suas tabelas devem estar sendo criadas como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pela sua questão, você precisaria de um mapeamento como o abaixo para ter um TPC:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties(); // necessário para indicar que Pessoas deve estar contido em Cliente
    m.ToTable("Cliente");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Fornecedor>().Map(m =>
{
    m.MapInheritedProperties(); // necessário para indicar que Pessoas deve estar contido em Fornecedor
    m.ToTable("Fornecedor");
});
```

Dessa forma, suas tabelas seriam criadas como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso, como para o Entity Framework temos apenas o tipo Pessoa, para pegar apenas Clientes você precisaria fazer algo como:

```
var clientes = contexto.Pessoas.OfType<Cliente>().ToList();
```

O que deve ser considerado também é que, pela natureza do seu mapeamento entre classes, fazer um comando contexto.Pessoas.ToList() geraria sempre uma query com UNION ALL entre todas as tabelas de tipos filhos. Por conta disso, o recomendado é que seja verificado muito bem o tipo de querys que você pretende fazer para esse tipo de mapeamento.

> 2º - Na entidade Endereco ele vai possuir apenas numero, complemento, cep e o IdPessoa. Porem não sei se isso é possivel. Se não for eu posso ter na mesma entidade ( endereco ) atributos como IdCliente, IdFornecedor ... Id .... conforme for precisando e somente preenchendo de acordo com a entidade persistida ( Na minha visao , tenho quase certeza que isso seria uma gambiarra ), qual seria a alternativa uma tabela pra cada entidade tipo ClienteEndereco, FornecedorEndereco e se for isso como ficaria minhas classes e o mapeamento ?

Se na sua entidade de Endereço os campos forem sempre iguais, ela se relacioná com Pessoa e terá apenas o PessoaId que você definiu na classe abstrata.

As entidades ficariam algo como:

```
public abstract class Pessoa
{
    public Guid IdPessoa { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente : Pessoa
{
    public Cliente()
    {
        IdPessoa = Guid.NewGuid();
        //Enderecos = new List<Endereco>();
    }

    public string CPF { get; set; }
}

public class Fornecedor : Pessoa
{
    public Fornecedor()
    {
        IdPessoa = Guid.NewGuid();
        //Enderecos = new List<Endereco>();
    }

    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco
{
    public int IdEndereco { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Complemento { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }

    public Guid IdPessoa { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

E o mapeamento de Endereco ficaria:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Endereco>().HasKey(x => x.IdEndereco);
modelBuilder.Entity<Endereco>().Property(x => x.IdEndereco)
                               .IsRequired()
                               .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

modelBuilder.Entity<Endereco>().Property(x => x.Numero)
                               .IsRequired()
                               .IsUnicode(false)
                               .HasColumnType("varchar")
                               .HasMaxLength(5);

modelBuilder.Entity<Endereco>().Property(x => x.Complemento)
                               .IsRequired()
                               .IsUnicode(false)
                               .HasColumnType("varchar")
                               .HasMaxLength(100);

modelBuilder.Entity<Endereco>().Property(x => x.Cep)
                               .IsRequired()
                               .IsFixedLength()
                               .IsUnicode(false)
                               .HasColumnType("char")
                               .HasMaxLength(8);

modelBuilder.Entity<Endereco>().Property(x => x.IdPessoa)
                               .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>().HasMany<Endereco>(pessoa => pessoa.Enderecos)
                             .WithRequired(endereco => endereco.Pessoa)
                             .HasForeignKey(endereco => endereco.IdPessoa);
```

Considerando que estamos adicionando 3 endereços como abaixo:

```
using (var contexto = new Contexto())
{
    var cliente = new Cliente { CPF = "74182476808" }; // gerado aleatoriamente
    contexto.Pessoas.Add(cliente);

    var fornecedor = new Fornecedor { CNPJ = "89205398000106" }; // gerado aleatoriamente
    contexto.Pessoas.Add(fornecedor);

    var enderecoCliente1 = new Endereco { Numero = "1", Cep = "00000000", Complemento = "Teste endereço cliente 1", Pessoa = cliente };
    contexto.Enderecos.Add(enderecoCliente1);

    var enderecoCliente2 = new Endereco { Numero = "2", Cep = "00000000", Complemento = "Teste endereço cliente 2 ", Pessoa = cliente };
    contexto.Enderecos.Add(enderecoCliente2);

    var enderecoFornecedor = new Endereco { Numero = "3", Cep = "00000000", Complemento = "Teste endereço fornecedor", Pessoa = fornecedor };
    contexto.Enderecos.Add(enderecoFornecedor);

    contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

Dessa forma, independentemente se você estiver usando TPT ou TPC e você quiser, por exemplo, apenas os clientes e seus respectivos endereços, você faria:

```
var clientes = contexto.Pessoas.Include("Enderecos").OfType<Cliente>().ToList();
```

Isso geraria uma query como:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[IdPessoa] AS [IdPessoa], 
    [Project1].[CPF] AS [CPF], 
    [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[IdEndereco] AS [IdEndereco], 
    [Project1].[Numero] AS [Numero], 
    [Project1].[Complemento] AS [Complemento], 
    [Project1].[Cep] AS [Cep], 
    [Project1].[IdPessoa1] AS [IdPessoa1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[IdPessoa] AS [IdPessoa], 
        [Extent1].[CPF] AS [CPF], 
        '0X0X' AS [C1], 
        1 AS [C2], 
        [Extent2].[IdEndereco] AS [IdEndereco], 
        [Extent2].[Numero] AS [Numero], 
        [Extent2].[Complemento] AS [Complemento], 
        [Extent2].[Cep] AS [Cep], 
        [Extent2].[IdPessoa] AS [IdPessoa1], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[IdEndereco] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C3]
        FROM  [dbo].[Cliente] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Enderecoes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IdPessoa] = [Extent2].[IdPessoa]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[IdPessoa] ASC, [Project1].[C3] ASC
```

E finalmente, o resultado seria:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Importante**: como estamos falando de Cliente e Fornecedor como tabelas diferentes e sem relação, o campo "IdPessoa" da tabela Endereco nunca terá uma FK.

Se essa chave é crucial para seu caso, é recomendado o uso de TPT para Pessoa ou, no pior caso, deixe a lista de Endereços em cada Pessoa e fique com N campos NULL na tabela Endereco para lidar com cada um dos filhos de Pessoa.

Comment: @cigano-morrison-mendez desculpe a demora pra clicar no aceitar , é que praticamente não consegui finalizar o projeto , só retomei agora , definitivamente funcionou !

Answer (score 3):

> 1º - Usar o migration para criar a base, mas no meu teste ele gera a tabela pessoa com todos os atributos e as classes que estendem Pessoa apenas com o IdPessoa e a propriedade particular de cada uma. Gostaria de saber se posso usar ou se tenho que mapear na unha?

Isso ocorre porque você mapeou `Pessoa` com um `DbSet` correspondente no contexto. Neste caso, o Entity Framework entende que `Cliente` e `Fornecedor` estendem `Pessoa` e colocam todos os campos na mesma tabela, o que é correto, já que você pode usar assim:

```
var pessoas = db.Pessoas.ToList();
```

Essa consulta traz todas as pessoas, independentes de serem clientes ou fornecedores. Se você deseja manter clientes e fornecedores separados, remova o `DbSet` de `Pessoa` e gere o banco de dados novamente.

> 2º - Na entidade Endereco ele vai possuir apenas numero, complemento, cep e o IdPessoa. Porem não sei se isso é possivel. Se não for eu posso ter na mesma entidade ( endereco ) atributos como IdCliente, IdFornecedor ... Id .... conforme for precisando e somente preenchendo de acordo com a entidade persistida ( Na minha visao , tenho quase certeza que isso seria uma gambiarra ), qual seria a alternativa uma tabela pra cada entidade tipo ClienteEndereco, FornecedorEndereco e se for isso como ficaria minhas classes e o mapeamento?

Resolvendo o ponto 1 resolve-se automaticamente por design o ponto 2, ou seja, não precisará existir `ClienteEndereco` e `FornecedorEndereco` se você usar a estrutura unificada de tabelas com a herança. Apenas `Endereco` já resolve bem o que você precisa.

Agora, se a intenção é deixar `Cliente` e `Fornecedor` em tabelas separadas, você terá que realizar o mapeamento de `ClienteEndereco` e `FornecedorEndereco`, respectivamente, e poderá usar não necessariamente `IdPessoa`. Pode usar `IdCliente` ou `IdFornecedor`, apenas indicando ao Entity Framework as propriedades de navegação corretas, ou seja, para `ClienteEndereco`:

```
public int ClienteId { get; set; }
public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
```

E para `Fornecedor`:

```
public int FornecedorId { get; set; }
public virtual Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
```

Como disse em comentário, se você quer unificar os endereços, mas especializando por Cliente e Fornecedor, terá também que colocar a herança em `Endereco`:

```
public abstract class Endereco { ... }
public class ClienteEndereco : Endereco { ... }
public class FornecedorEndereco { ... }
```

Comment: Náo entendi @cigano-morrison-mendez, a minha classe pessoa náo esta no meu mapeamento e tmb nao esta no meu dbset, náo entendi porque o  migration capturou a classe

Comment: Reli minha resposta e acho que ela ficou bem ruim, então mudei tudo. Espero que agora esteja mais esclarecida.

Comment: Cara desculpa, mas continuo sem enteder a sua resposta. Acho que não expliquei, mas eu não estou mapeando Pessoa, pessoa é apenas uma classe abstrata, eu faço mapeamento apenas das classes que a herdam. A ideia central é ter tabelas separadas Cliente/ Fornecedor herdando de Pessoa ( abstrata ) e uma tabela endereço recebendo o idPessoa propriedade que é herdada da entidade abstrata. Porem o migration esta lendo a minha entidade cliente e criando uma tabela para cada tanto para pessoa quanto para cliente.

Comment: Então, como eu disse agora na resposta (agora sim tá correta) que `Pessoa` não pode ter `DbSet` no contexto, senão ela será mapeada. Nos endereços você até pode usar `PessoaId` pra referenciar, mas não precisa ser com pessoa. Pode ser outro nome. Apenas faça as referências das propriedades `Cliente` e `Fornecedor` que o Entity Framework fará o resto.

Comment: Só um adendo eu não quero fazer entidades separadas porque preciso controlar propriedades extras ja que a minha entidade com dados do logradouro é a parte da entidade endereço que deveria conter apenas o idPessoa ( entidades cliente / fornecedor ... lembrando que cada uma tem sua propria tabela) , codigoCep ( cep ), numero e complento.

Comment: Então cara mas nao tem dbset pessoa o unico dbset é cliente e fornecedor mais nada é por isso que não estou entendendo, eu nao tenho nada referenciando Pessoa

Comment: Sobre a permanência de `Pessoa`, creio ser alguma particularidade no seu projeto. Agora, unificar `ClienteEndereco` e `FornecedorEndereco` numa só tabela com "propriedades extras" só é possível se houver uma entidade `Endereco` e as outras duas entidades sejam derivadas dela.

Comment: Se quiser, posso colocar isto na minha resposta. Não sei se precisa.

Comment: Cara coloca, ainda não to conseguindo vislumbrar a parada toda. Na teoria pra mim era simples, coloco uma classe abstrata , tenho uma derivada dessa abstrata, mapeio essa derivada e o migration cria a tabela da derivada e nao das duas, na minha tabela endereço recebe o idPessoa (propriedade herdada ) e dessa derivada ou de qqr outra derivada dessa abstrata, numa unica tabela endereço com um unico campo idpessoa .... mas ja vi que vou ter que dar algumas voltas pra fazer isso funcionar .