# Dúvida sobre entidades asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Tenho 4 tabelas: *T1*, *T2*, *T3* e *T4* e a tabela de *Clientes*.

O que acontece é que as tabelas *T2* a *T4* "deveriam" ser uma só. Mas como parte dos dados seriam como se fosse uma tabela e suas opções, preferi quebrar para ficar mais fácil da manutenção...

Seria coisa do tipo, me referindo aos dados de como se fossem um tabela:

> **|Tipo|Horario|Quantidade|**
>
> **|A   | 12:00 | 4        |**

Por isso preferi colocar em tabelas diferentes para facilitar....

Mas agora não se sei como fazer salvar isso no banco de dados... Pois preciso cadastrar tudo ao mesmo tempo. Ou seja, seria uma forma de cascata: após cadastrar o cliente, ele fosse relacionado na *T2*. Após a *T2* ter sido cadastrada, relacionar ela com as demais (*T3* e *T4*)...

Como poderia fazer isso usando o *Entity Framework*? Como poderia fazer, já que não preciso gerar um controller e views(poderiam ser partial views) para isso? Minha abordagem esta correta ou eu deveria fazer tudo em uma tabela só?

Espero ter sido claro.

Comment: Seria como se você estivesse salvando algo tipo Cliente e telefone por exemplo é isso ?

Comment: Isso... Tipo Cliente, Telefone e Endereço..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tenta usar o link a baixo para ver se ajuda com seu problema

[Fluent API e Migration](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109602/fluent-api-e-migration/109913#109913)